# Notation when accessing sequence elements in recusive formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

I'm currently studying the tick rule and wanted to denote it formally. However, I'm unsure about my notation when accessing sequence elements in a piece-wise function.

**Background:**

found in (https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1540-6261.1991.tb02683.x):

> “A trade is an uptick (downtick) if the price is higher (lower) than the price of the previous trade. When the price is the same as the previous trade (a zero tick), if the last price change was an uptick, then the trade is a zero-uptick. Similarly, if the last price change was a downtick, then the trade is a zero-downtick. A trade is classified as a buy if it occurs on an uptick or a zero-uptick; otherwise it is classified as a sell”

**My description:**

Let $(p_t)_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence of trade prices ordered by time. I've now defined the tick rule as:
$$
  \operatorname{tick}\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \left\{0,1\right\}\quad \operatorname{tick}(p_{t-1}, p_{t})=
  \begin{cases}
    1,                                         & \text{if}\ p_{t} > p_{t-1} \\
    0,                                         & \text{if}\ p_{t} < p_{t-1} \\
    \operatorname{tick}(p_{t-2}, p_{t-1}), & \text{else}.
  \end{cases}
$$

What makes me wonder if my notation is correct regarding the else case, as I don't pass $p_{t-2}$ (or any other previous element) to the function, and what is a better way to denote it?
Basically, I want to find the last element before $p_t$ that is different from $p_t$ and classify it.

Please feel free to point me to a broader concept if there is some.

EDIT: fixed typo in else branch ($p_t$ to $p_{t-1}$)

Comment: How about $\operatorname{tick}\colon \mathbb{R} \to \left\{0,1\right\}\quad \operatorname{tick}(t)=
  \begin{cases}
    1,                                         & \text{if}\ p_{t} > p_{t-1} \\
    0,                                         & \text{if}\ p_{t} < p_{t-1} \\
    \operatorname{tick}(t-1), & \text{else}.
  \end{cases}$. Also in your version $\operatorname{tick}(p_{t-2}, p_{t})$ should have been $\operatorname{tick}(p_{t-2}, p_{t-1})$. The assumption is there's an array trade prices where $p_i$ references an element of the array.

Comment: @StevenClark Thanks for your comment and for spotting my typo. Your version is much clearer. If you want, you can turn it into an answer, that I can accept. Just out of curiosity is there also an option to pass the trade prices rather than the index as a parameter? (similar to my initial idea)

Comment: If you want you could pass the array of trade prices (or a pointer to the array of trade prices) in as a parameter as well as the index $t$, but the recursion is only safe if the entire history of trade prices is stored in the array. Also some convention must be assumed for the first entry in the array (i.e. $p_1=1$ or $p_1=0$ assuming $p_1$ corresponds to the first array entry).

Comment: I suppose you could pass in only the array (or a pointer to the array} and omit the $t$ parameter where the assumption is the last element of the array corresponds to the index $t$, but this would require shortening the array with each recursion and a provision for determining the length of the array which corresponding to the index $t$.

Comment: @StevenClark. Thanks for your thoughts on this. Based on your comments, passing only the index and accessing the elements seems more reasonable to me. I'll take care of the first elements so that the recursion eventually ends, if not earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the following

$$\operatorname{tick}\colon\mathbb{N}\to\left\{0,1\right\}\quad\operatorname{tick}(t)=\begin{cases} 1, & t=1\lor p_{t}>p_{t-1} \\ 0, & p_{t}<p_{t-1} \\ \operatorname{tick}(t-1), & p_{t}=p_{t-1}\end{cases}$$

where the assumption is there's an array $p$ of trade prices where $p_t$ references an element of the array for $t\in\mathbb{N}$ and the $t=1$ condition corresponding to the first entry in the array assures the recursion doesn't go beyond the beginning of the array $p$.